# Extract items within </h> but without <h> from html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped a website that provides me with Lisbon zip-codes. With BeautifulSoup I was able to get the zip-codes within a class item. However, the zip-codes themselves are still within other classes and I have tried many things to extract all of them from there. However, except for string-manipulation, I couldn't make it work. I am new to webscraping and html, so sorry if this question is very basic..

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get

url='https://worldpostalcode.com/portugal/lisboa/'
response = get(url)
print(response.text)
html_soup = soup(response.text,'lxml')
type(html_soup)
zip_codes=html_soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'rightc'})
```

And this is a snippet of the result from which I would like to only extract the zip codes..

```
[<div class="rightc">1000-246<hr/> 1050-138<hr/> 1069-188<hr/> 1070-204<hr/> 1100-069<hr/> 1100-329<hr/> 1100-591<hr/> 1150-144<hr/> 1169-062<hr/> 1170-128<hr/> 1170-395<hr/> 1200-228<hr/> 1200-604<hr/> 1200-862<hr/> 1250-111<hr/> 1269-121<hr/> 1300-217<hr/> 1300-492<hr/> 1350-092<hr/> 1399-014<hr/> 1400-237<hr/> 1500-061<hr/> 1500-360<hr/> 1500-674<hr/> 1600-232<hr/> 1600-643<hr/> 1700-018<hr/> 1700-302<hr/> 1750-113<hr/> 1750-464<hr/> 1800-262<hr/> 1900-115<hr/> 1900-401<hr/> 1950-208<hr/> 1990-162<hr/> 1000-247<hr/> 1050-139<hr/> 1069-190<hr/> 1070-205<hr/> 1100-070<hr/> 1100-330</div>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,'lxml')
type(html_soup)
zip_codes=html_soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'rightc'})

print(zip_codes[0].text.split(' '))
```

you can get the `text` and `split` it.

o/p :

```
[u'1000-246', u'1050-138', u'1069-188', u'1070-204',.........]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your result `zip_codes` has the type `bs4.element.ResultSet`, which is a set of `bs4.element.Tag`. So `zip_codes[0]` is what you're interested in (the first tag found). Use the `.text` method to strip the `<hr>` tags. Now you have a long string of zip codes separated by spaces. Strip them out into a list somehow (two options below, option one is more pythonic and faster).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get

url = 'https://worldpostalcode.com/portugal/lisboa/'
response = get(url)
html_soup = soup(response.text,'lxml')
zip_codes = html_soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'rightc'})

# option one
zips = zip_codes[0].text.split(' ')
print(zips[:8])

# option two (slower)
zips = []
for zc in zip_codes[0].childGenerator():
    zips.append(zc.extract().strip())
print(zips[:8])
```

Output:

```
['1000-246', '1050-138', '1069-188', '1070-204', '1100-069', '1100-329', '1100-591', '1150-144']
['1000-246', '1050-138', '1069-188', '1070-204', '1100-069', '1100-329', '1100-591', '1150-144']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to grab the codes

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://worldpostalcode.com/portugal/lisboa/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
element = soup.select_one('.codelist .rightc')
codes = re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{3}",element.text)

for code in codes:
    print(code)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to replace all the `</hr>`tags into some `delimiter (i.e., # or $ or ,)` before loading the page response as soup. Now the job will be so easy once you load it into the soup you can extract the zip codes as a list just by calling the class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get

url='https://worldpostalcode.com/portugal/lisboa/'
response = get(url)
print(response.text.replace('<hr>', '#'))
html_soup = soup(response.text,'lxml')
type(html_soup)
zip_codes=html_soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'rightc'})
zip_codes = zip_codes.text.split('#')
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

P.S.: Answer is open for improvements and comments.